# Is there an elegant way in Ruby to filter a hash of arrays of hashses?

Tags: ruby, filter, ruby-hash

Let's say I have a this type of data structure:

```
{
  "foo": [{state: on}, {state: off}, {state: on}],
  "bar": [{state: off}, {state: off}, {state: on}],
  "baz": [{state: on}, {state: on}, {state: on}]
}
```

How can I filter the nested hash arrays in an elegant way so I can get back this:

```
{
  "foo": [{state: on}, {state: on}],
  "bar": [{state: on}],
  "baz": [{state: on}, {state: on}, {state: on}]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a={
    "foo": [{state: "on"}, {state: "off"}, {state: "on"}],
    "bar": [{state: "off"}, {state: "off"}, {state: "on"}],
    "baz": [{state: "on"}, {state: "on"}, {state: "on"}]
}
```

Code

```
p a.transform_values{|arr| arr.select{|h|h[:state].eql?'on'}}
```

Result

```
{:foo=>[{:state=>"on"}, {:state=>"on"}], :bar=>[{:state=>"on"}], :baz=>[{:state=>"on"}, {:state=>"on"}, {:state=>"on"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
data = {
  "foo": [{state: :on}, {state: :off}, {state: :on}],
  "bar": [{state: :off}, {state: :off}, {state: :on}],
  "baz": [{state: :on}, {state: :on}, {state: :on}]
}
```

Use `#transform_values` to iterate and replace the hash values and `#select` to filter the elements in the array:

```
data.transform_values do |value|
  value.select { |hash| hash[:state] == :on  }
end
```

Comment: ahHH `transform_keys`! I have not seen this yet. Brilliant!

Comment: Ooops, should have been transform_values